My light doesnt work
I'm a noob in Blender, and I'm trying to make a project for university. So I'm making this building and I wanted to render it to see how it's going, but my light doesn't work. I mean, it works, but in a tiny way.
As you can see, the light only lights up a really small place. This building is 19 m X, 19 m Y and 2.5 m Z, am I doing something wrong?


This is like a tiny light bulb with a strength of 10 W (if it's still on default settings) trying to light up a huge building.
Since buildings are usually lit on the outside by the sun and the sky, I would rather add a Sun lamp to your scene instead of a Point light with Shift+A > Add > Light > Sun and rotate it to your liking. Also increase the Strength to a higher value.


Then I would maybe change the World to a sky blue instead of a dark grey.

However, this is just some basic lighting to make your scene brighter. This is far from having realistic lighting - therefore you might look into HDRI lighting or using the Sky Texture for the world etc., but I am not going to write a complete tutorial and there are different solutions depending on what you're aiming for. I would highly recommend you watch tutorials on lighting scenes, and especially for outdoor / environment scenes to get at least an idea how this all works and what possibilities there are.

Go to the light properties and increase its strength/intensity/power


I would also suggest to move the light away from the roof, if it is to model some sun light...

@StefLAncien Or better directly use a Sun lamp instead of the default Point light to get something that's more like sunlight...
